# object: SearchView.OnQueryTextListener is giving error in android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, searchview

I am trying to build a weather app using openweather api.I am trying to find the weather report of a city by searching the city name on the search bar.Have tried some solutions by everytime either the app crashes or search bar becomes unclickable.
Search bar in xml file
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
android:id="@+id/searchView"

```
    android:layout_width="0dp"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"

    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"

    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"

    android:background="@drawable/searchviewshape"

    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"

    android:queryHint="Search For A City"

    android:searchIcon="@drawable/search"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Mainactivity function
val searchView = binding.searchView

```
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object: SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
            if (!query.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                fetchWeatherData(query)
            }
            return true
        }
        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
            // Handle text change if needed
            return false
        }
    })
```

I tried to implement a function such that if i search for a city it will shows its weather report.But unfortunately it is not working .Even when in xml file when i set the search view as only <SearchView rather than <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView it throws an error.